# Doubt in URL hacking - "un" for username though id is "username"

Tags: urlhacking

To login into salesforce without entering `username`, one is supposed to use - 
https://login.salesforce.com/?un=abc@abc.com

**This works fine.** But when I inspect the "username" element, the ID of the field is actually username and not un!! 
Then how and why is this working?

Comment: You can think that Salesforce reads the parameter `un`. Parameter `username` would not work

Comment: but - why is my question?

Comment: If you inspect element you can see a input hidden with name `un` try to search with `un` name

Comment: Yes Ratan, there is a hidden element "un". But how am I supposed to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-configured set of attributes which Salesforce uses for its internal use when need to perform specific operations. Those operation can be:
Page Language, Authentication, page theme etc.

This is part of architecting Salesforce login page so frequent things can be handled without any code modification. These attributes are generally used when Salesforce interact with its other sites like developer community, partner community, Login via mobile device etc.

As all these things are for **internal use only** so Salesforce has not documented it and does not suppose to use these core attributes in custom implementations over the platform.

It has no connection with code behavior that if form element has same Id then parameter with that Id would capture value of it. That's their design.